# "Auto hide toolbar" in Samsung Android Browser breaks non-scrollable pages (SGS5/Lollipop)

Tags: hide, toolbar

We have discovered a problem with "auto-hide toolbar" feature of Samsung android browser (tested on SGS5, Android version 5.0).

It is enabled by default and shows address bar, when page is scrolled up (hides it when page is scrolled down).

However, it breaks web application with no scrollable content. For example, on every up/down swipe gesture in my web game address bar is shown/hidden (and game is shifted up/down constantly):
http://jellimatic.com/games/rhinorink/7d6db8bb376c/

This is not limited to web games, it breaks other types of applications as well, for example, ones which scroll content inside their own container:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290414-(Samsung-Galaxy-S5)-browser-address-bar-issue

Is there are way to indicate to Samsung browser that this particular page is not scrollable (and thus auto-hide cannot work)?

What I have (unsuccessfully) tried:
- Ensured I have proper viewporter meta-tag
- Added preventDefault() calls to all of the touch/mouse events
- Ensured I have overflow: hidden on body tag
- Use fullscreen API to switch browser to full screen mode

Is there a way to suppress un-wanted hide/show address bar for non-scrollable web pages/apps? If not, what is the best way to log an issue for Samsung attention on that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have achieved it:

```
            html{
                background-color: red;
                overflow: hidden;
                width:100%;
            }
            body{
                height:100%;
                position:fixed; /* prevent overscroll bounce*/
                background-color: lightgreen;
                overflow-y:scroll;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* iOS velocity scrolling */
                width:50%;                    
                margin-left:25%;
            }
```